# When is JMXBean initialised

Tags: java, jmx

IMEI I am new to MXbeans. I want to understand when is the MXBean actually initialized, in the application which I am supporting we have a notification system and I can not see my MXBean in JConsole until there is some notification arriving. Here is a code of my MXBean.

```
    package mecomaany.instrumentation;

    import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.management.Attribute;
    import javax.management.AttributeList;
    import javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException;
    import javax.management.DynamicMBean;
    import javax.management.InvalidAttributeValueException;
    import javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo;
    import javax.management.MBeanException;
    import javax.management.MBeanInfo;
    import javax.management.MBeanOperationInfo;
    import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
    import javax.management.ObjectName;
    import javax.management.ReflectionException;

    import  BulkCMIRP_MxBean;
    import SoapIRPLogger;

    /**
     * This dynamic MBean exposes a method to return the 10 latest Basic CM
     * operations.
     * 
 * @author eshtrom
 * 
 */
    public class BasicCMIRP_MxBean implements DynamicMBean{
    private static final String CLASS_NAME =        BasicCMIRP_MxBean.class.getCanonicalName();
    private static final String MX_BEAN_NAME =   BasicCMIRP_MxBean.class.getCanonicalName() + ":Type=BasicCMIRP_MxBean";
    private static final String BEAN_DESCRIPTION = "Instrumentation bean for SOAP Basic CM IRP.";
    private static final int NUM_OPERATIONS_TO_RECORD = 10;
    private final ArrayList<String> basicCMOperations = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * Register the bean. This is a best effort attempt. If registration fails
     * we'll report it but nothing more.
     */
    public BasicCMIRP_MxBean() {
        registerMxBean();
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to unregister and clean up the MX beans.
     */
    public void destroy() {
        basicCMOperations.clear();
        unregisterMxBean();
    }

    /**
     * This method returns a description of this bean to the JMX interface. The
     * description is just a list of names of the currently stored attributes.
     */
    public synchronized MBeanInfo getMBeanInfo() {
        final MBeanAttributeInfo[] attributes = new MBeanAttributeInfo[0];
        final MBeanOperationInfo[] operations = { new MBeanOperationInfo("getBasicCMInstrumentation", "Get instrumentation Basic CM IRP bean.", null, "String[]",
                MBeanOperationInfo.INFO) };
        return new MBeanInfo(this.getClass().getName(), BEAN_DESCRIPTION, attributes, null, operations, null);
    }



    /**
     * Callback to execute methods exposed by this dynamic MBean.
     */
    public Object invoke(final String actionName, final Object[] params, final String[] signature) throws MBeanException, ReflectionException {
        SoapIRPLogger.enter(CLASS_NAME, "invoke");
        if (actionName != null) {
            if (actionName.equals("getBulkCMInstrumentation")) {
                return getBasicCMInstrumentation();
            }
        }
        SoapIRPLogger.exit(CLASS_NAME, "invoke");
        throw new ReflectionException(new NoSuchMethodException(actionName));
    }


    /**
     * Construct a human readable very of the last 10 operations and return it.
     * 
     * @return string array as an object.
     */
    private Object getBasicCMInstrumentation() {
        SoapIRPLogger.enter(CLASS_NAME, "getBasicCMInstrumentation");
        String[] result = new String[basicCMOperations.size()];
        int index = 0;
        for (String operation : basicCMOperations) {
            result[index] = operation;
            index++;
        }
        SoapIRPLogger.exit(CLASS_NAME, "getBasicCMInstrumentation");
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * No attributes are writable so this method will throw an exception.
     */
    public void setAttribute(final Attribute arg0) throws AttributeNotFoundException, InvalidAttributeValueException, MBeanException, ReflectionException {
        throw new AttributeNotFoundException("All attributes on this bean are read only.");
    }

    /**
     * No attributes are writable so this method will return an empty list.
     */
    public AttributeList setAttributes(final AttributeList arg0) {
        return new AttributeList();
    }


    public Object getAttribute(final String attribute) throws AttributeNotFoundException, MBeanException, ReflectionException {
        throw new AttributeNotFoundException("No attributes are defined on this MX bean.");
    }

    /**
     * No attributes are readable so this method will return an empty list.
     */
    public AttributeList getAttributes(final String[] attributes) {
        return new AttributeList();
    }

    /**
     * Add or update and instrumentation attribute. A null attribute name will
     * be ignored.
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param value
     */
    public void updateInstrumentationAttibute(final String name, final String value) {
        // The only attribute that this bean supports is Bulk CM operations.
        if (name.compareTo("BasicCM_Operations") == 0) {
            basicCMOperations.add(value);
            // We'll only record a maximum of 10 operations. If we exceed the
            // max, remove the oldest.
            if (basicCMOperations.size() > NUM_OPERATIONS_TO_RECORD) {
                basicCMOperations.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }


    public ObjectName getBeanName() throws MalformedObjectNameException, NullPointerException {
        // Construct the ObjectName for the MBean we will register
        return new ObjectName(MX_BEAN_NAME);
    }

    /**
     * Register the bean.
     */
    protected void registerMxBean() {
        try {
            ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().registerMBean(this, this.getBeanName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SoapIRPLogger.exception(CLASS_NAME, "Constructor", "Failed to register BulkCMIRP_MxBean management beans.", e);
        }
    }
    protected void unregisterMxBean() {
        try {
            ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().unregisterMBean(this.getBeanName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Suppress exceptions, we're closing down anyway.
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: yes you right, I have just written this code so at them moment it is not yet part of the company's repository, but you right

Comment: Gentleman, what about the question . Can you explain me how the initialisation works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loner;

Your MXBean should be visible in JConsole as soon as you construct it, since the constructor calls **registerMxBean()** which registers the MBean with the platform MBeanServer.

Assuming your JConsole is already running when the MBean is registered, JConsole's view of the MBean will be dictated by the first instance of the MBeanInfo that is generated on registration. Since you coded this as a **DynamicMBean**, I wonder if your intent was to periodically modify the MBeanInfo, but be aware that once a JConsole connection has retrieved the MBeanInfo for a registered bean, it will not refresh it. If the MBeanInfo changes, you must closed the connection in JConsole and open it again.

Consequently, your issue may be outside the code you have supplied, or more simply put, when is the instance of **BasicCMIRP_MxBean** created ?

Your comment about not seeing the bean until notifications start arriving makes me wonder if you mean that:
A. You cannot see the MBean until notifications start arriving, in which case I would assume that there is some activation code that creates the instance when a [the first ?] notification arrives, or
B. What you mean is that you cannot see specific properties of the MBean until notifications start arriving.

Perhaps you could clarify the larger picture here.

Some additional observations that may be unrelated:

1. The MBeanInfo you are generating specifies that the one and only operation is called **getBasicCMInstrumentation** (basic), but your *invoke* handler only attempts to decode an operation called **getBulkCMInstrumentation** (bulk). JConsole is supplied the MBeanInfo in order to render the operations so the console believes that the operation is called *basic* but the MBean will only respond to a request called *bulk*.
2. The signature for method **getBasicCMInstrumentation** returns an **Object** but what the code really returns is a **String[]**. This may work because your MBeanInfo specifies that a *String[]* is returned, but for consistency and clarity I would change the method signature.

//Nicholas

Comment: nicholas, I actually found some code which invokes creation of the Bean so I totally understand how it works now